# Dragging from one d3 visualization to another

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, d3.js

I'm designing a [d3](http://d3js.org/) visualization, but I'm not particularly experienced with the library and I'm not sure if something is possible, or easy.

I want to instantiate it twice on the page, and drag elements from one to the other;

```
+--------------+             +--------------+
|              |             |              |
|     vis1     |             |     vis2     |
|         [x]------drag--------->           |
|              |             |              |
|              |             |              |
+--------------+             +--------------+
```

Are there any samples, documentation, or tutorials which explain how to do this in code?

Thanks